# Using capital Y in you when writing to many

Tags: meaning, differences

Can you use capital Y in you when adressing to more than 1 person?

Comment: I think people would probably interpret it as addressing God. Note that we don't capitalize 'they' or 'them'.

Comment: Even using "He", "Him", "His", etc about God is somewhat archaic these days.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - You capitalize "you" when it's at the start of a sentence, don't you?

Comment: Marja Sittala: Only capitalise 'You' at the start of a sentence.

Comment: Can you?  Yes.  Should you?  Not unless you want to be thought strange.  In some languages this may commonly be done, but not in English.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is universally accepted or understood as referring to a group. In type, it would likely be viewed as a typo. Additionally, others have commented in this answer to the same end:
["you" versus "You" as polite form of writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30185/you-versus-you-as-polite-form-of-writing)

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.